# Inverse function Khan Academy

Tags: inverse-function

[image: Khan Academy Inverse Function exercise]

I'm doing an exercise on inverse functions on Khan Academy and cannot get with the first exercise. Where to find number $93$? There is no such number in the table...

Comment: By definition $f^{-1}$ is the function that undo the function $f$, which means that $f^{-1}(f(a))=a$ for all $a$ in the domain

Comment: Ok thanks i got it!!!

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of the inverse fuction, $$f^{-1}\left ( f(93) \right )=93.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what *is* the inverse function $f^{-1}$?

Comment: Ok thanks i got it!!!